# How to make image move on hover with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a background image but no html with  tags but I want to make the background image move on hove with some type of javascript. But when I add the img tag into the html it covers everything else. Here is a live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/X7UwG/) I don't know that much javascript so I'm stuck.

```
body { background-image: url('images/bg_2880.jpg'); }
```

I need the javascript to move the image on the mouse hover like this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7UwG/)

Comment: Whats wrong with the example you linked? Why not just plug your image url into that code? You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to help you with your code.

Comment: @Ethical38 I think you just answered your own question

Comment: When I add the image tag it covers everything on this web page https://getmdl.io/templates/blog/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called a *parallax* effect

Simple example:

```js
addEventListener('mousemove', ev => {
  const force = 100;
  const dx = -ev.clientX / window.innerWidth * force;
  const dy = -ev.clientY / window.innerHeight * force;
  document.body.style.backgroundPositionX = dx + 'px';
  document.body.style.backgroundPositionY = dy + 'px';
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/800/800");
}
```